# Gnome Terminal PID

Tags: bash, terminal, gnome

How can I get the PID of a TERMINAL running a process with given PID? For example, I open a new terminal and run it a process, say ". / dbserver", then I have the PID of the process using `pidof dbServer`, so I want the PID of the terminal that is running dbserver. bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `ps -f` includes the parent PID of each process.  You could also use `-o ppid` along with whichever other fields you are interested in.

Comment: Yes but, how i can get the parent pid of determined pid ?

Comment: `ps --no-headers -o ppid -p $(pidof dbServer)`

Comment: Hey ... how can i return "0" if parent pid don't exists ?

Comment: How can a parent pid not exist?

Comment: The most similar to "a parent not existing" is when the parent pid has a value 1. This generally means that the original parent of the process was involved in a car accident and couldn't make it (it died), and the child became orphan, so it was attached as child of ~the the wilderness~ ```init``` or ~the government~ ```systemd```.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the Terminal is then that process's parent, see here: https://superuser.com/questions/150117/how-to-get-parent-pid-of-a-given-process-in-gnu-linux-from-command-line

```
ps -p `pidof dbserver` -o ppid=
```